# How to get the light or dark mode version of a SwiftUI Color?

Tags: swift, swiftui

How do I create a local variable with specifically the dark mode color in SwiftUI.
I am trying to avoid specifying the color scheme of each view to be dark to get the dark mode color.

For example in UIKit, I can get the dark mode color with this code

```
let traitCollection = UITraitCollection(userInterfaceStyle: .dark)
let darkModeBlueUIColor = UIColor.systemBlue.resolvedColor(with: traitCollection)
```

I know I can convert from a UIColor, but I want to specify it only using SwiftUI so it works on all platforms.

```
let darkModeBlueSwiftuiColor = Color(darkModeBlueUIColor)
```

I would like to do something like this involving a helper function

```
let darkModeBlueColor = Color.blue.darkModeColor
```

Answer (score 2):

To draw color for specific color schema just use it in view body as

```
    Color("testColor")
        .colorScheme(.dark)   // << this !!
```

also if you use color variable then same can be done.

Comment: Unfortunately this results in a View, not specifically a Color. You can't use it where a colour is expected (e.g. foregroundColor).

Answer (score 0):

If anyone drops by this question, heres a solution that I've found and use:

```
extension UIColor {
    var light: UIColor {
        resolvedColor(with: .init(userInterfaceStyle: .light))
    }

    var dark: UIColor {
        resolvedColor(with: .init(userInterfaceStyle: .dark))
    }
}
```

I found it [here](https://samwize.com/2022/06/29/asset-catalog-and-dark-mode/).

You can initialize a SwiftUI `Color` this way:

```
if let primary = UIColor(named: "primary") {
    let dark = Color(primary.dark)
    let light = Color(primary.light)
}
```